# Display arrays of JLabel

Tags: java, arrays, swing, layout-manager, null-layout-manager

For displaying 10 labels in a `JPanel` I used the following code using Netbeans, for Java.
Not getting the any output. `JPanel` layout set as `null` layout.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
   JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[10];
   for(int i=0; i<9; i++){
   labels[i] = new JLabel("Label Name " + i);
   p1.add(labels[i]);}
}
```

Comment: is the panel added to the frame?

Comment: What is p1? have you defined it?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).

Comment: *"`JPanel` layout set as `null` layout."*  Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Answer (score 3):

You need to call the [`validate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#validate--) method on the frame object after adding subcomponents to it.

> The validate method is used to cause a container to lay out its subcomponents again. It should be invoked when this container's subcomponents are modified (added to or removed from the container, or layout-related information changed) after the container has been displayed.